# winapi function for drawing isolated font characters

Tags: winapi

I'm working on a music notation program, and the musical symbols are provided in the form of a font. I'm using DrawTextW to render the symbols to the screen for now, but it doesn't seem very appropriate to use a function that takes a RECT parameter when I have to render the rectangle's size irrelevant by setting the background to transparent and setting the DT_NOCLIP option. Is there a way to draw a single font character that takes only an x and a y coordinate rather than a RECT?

Comment: What problem would that API solve?

Comment: See `TextOut()`.

Comment: @IInspectable It would get rid of the inconvenience of having to specify information that isn't relevant to a certain category of use cases. The API could certainly get away without providing what I describe, but I don't think it's unreasonable to imagine that it might exist.

Comment: @Danny_ds Thanks, this looks like just what I need.